# Efficiently sorting and filtering a JaggedArray by another one

Tags: awkward-array

I have a `JaggedArray` (`awkward.array.jagged.JaggedArray`) that contains indices that point to positions in another `JaggedArray`. Both arrays have the same length, but each of the `numpy.ndarrays` that the `JaggedArrays` contain can be of different length. I would like to sort the second array using the indices of the first array, at the same time dropping the elements from the second array that are not indexed from the first array. The first array can additionally contain values of `-1` (could also be replaced by `None` if needed, but this is currently not that case) that mean that there is no match in the second array. In such a case, the corresponding position in the first array should be set to a default value (e.g. `0`).

Here's a practical example and how I solve this at the moment:

```py
import uproot
import numpy as np
import awkward

def good_index(my_indices, my_values):
    my_list = []
    for index in my_indices:
        if index > -1:
            my_list.append(my_values[index])
        else:
            my_list.append(0)
    return my_list

indices = awkward.fromiter([[0, -1], [3,1,-1], [-1,0,-1]])
values = awkward.fromiter([[1.1, 1.2, 1.3], [2.1,2.2,2.3,2.4], [3.1]])

new_map = awkward.fromiter(map(good_index, indices, values))
```

The resulting `new_map` is: `[[1.1 0.0] [2.4 2.2 0.0] [0.0 3.1 0.0]]`.

Is there a more efficient/faster way achieving this? I was thinking that one could use `numpy` functionality such as `numpy.where`, but due to the different lengths of the `ndarrays` this fails at least for the ways that I tried.

Comment: Sorry that I didn't notice this until now! I thought I had set up email alerts, but I guess I didn't. Working on it now (for both [tag:uproot] and [tag:awkward-array]).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all of the subarrays in `values` are guaranteed to be non-empty (so that indexing with `-1` returns the last subelement, not an error), then you can do this:

```py
>>> almost = values[indices]       # almost what you want; uses -1 as a real index
>>> almost.content = awkward.MaskedArray(indices.content < 0, almost.content)
>>> almost.fillna(0.0)
<JaggedArray [[1.1 0.0] [2.4 2.2 0.0] [0.0 3.1 0.0]] at 0x7fe54c713c88>
```

The last step is optional because without it, the missing elements are `None`, rather than `0.0`.

If some of the subarrays in `values` are empty, you can `pad` them to ensure they have at least one subelement. All of the original subelements are indexed the same way they were before, since `pad` only increases the length, if need be.

```py
>>> values = awkward.fromiter([[1.1, 1.2, 1.3], [], [2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4], [], [3.1]])
>>> values.pad(1)
<JaggedArray [[1.1 1.2 1.3] [None] [2.1 2.2 2.3 2.4] [None] [3.1]] at 0x7fe54c713978>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is great and helped me! I actually discovered a bug in the ntuple production, namely that the indices can point to non-existing positions in the `values` subarray. I actually have access to a `numpy.ndarray` that tells me the size of the `values` subarray, e.g. for the example above it would be `valuesSize = np.array([3, 4, 1])` (could also get this via `values._stops-values._starts`). How can I make the above work preventing access to non-existing positions in the `values` subarray apart from padding `values` with a large number, i.e. extending on the 2nd part of your answer?

Comment: You can get the `[3, 4, 1]` array as `values.counts`. We really need an `awkward.where` function for issues like yours (https://github.com/scikit-hep/awkward-array/issues/84). A possible implementation just came to mind; click through that link to see it.

Comment: With `where`, you can do: `fixed_indices = awkward.where(indices < values.counts, indices, -1)` and then you only need to `pad(1)` to make sure that wrong indices, mapped to `-1`, picks up something that's not fake.